# Milder synonyms of "honored" in the "I'm honored" sense

Tags: synonyms

What are some synonyms of `honor` in the sense that `honored` is used in `I am honored`? I'm looking for a milder synonym specifically but this question can serve as a compendium of sorts for all synonyms in this sense.

There is `fortunate` but it signifies having something or getting something lasting, usually from the past and not necessarily with anyone else's actions involved.

There is `privileged` which is similar to honored but if anything it's stronger. Also, it cannot directly replace because it's used when what I'm getting has some lasting value.

If the President decides to thank me by sending me a letter, that would be an 'honor' but not a 'privilege'.

What I'm looking for is the word to use when my kind but not "important" neighbor decides to thank me by sending me a letter. 'honored' would be a very strong word to say in that case.

There's `humbled` too but I think it is, if anything, as strong as `honored`.

Comment: "I'm touched" might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Like both, thanks. Both these fit my specific requirement too.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, it fits what I'm looking for ...

Comment: I guess I'll make an answer then

Comment: ...*gratified.*

Comment: @YosefBaskin Do you want to add your comments as an answer- I want to accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While this might not be the site where this question can serve as a compendium of sorts for all synonyms, the words *flattered* or *delighted* are similar to and milder than *honored*.

> **Flatter**--To please or gratify the vanity of: "What really flatters a man is that you think him worth flattering" (George Bernard Shaw). [American Heritage, 5th Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flattered)
>
> **Delight**--Extremely pleased (to do something): I'm delighted to hear it! [Collins English Dictionary 12th Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/delighted)

Comment: Isn't it that 'honored' is more of a formal and serious nature compared to flattered or delighted which could be used in causal ways?  E.g., when people acknowledge you say in a party/ reception, you are honored; not flattered. Flattery could be insincere whereas 'being honored' is a public acceptance. Just an observation!

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps, ***pleased*** works here.

ODO:

> **[pleased](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pleased)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Feeling or showing pleasure and satisfaction, especially at an event or a situation.
>
> ‘he seemed really pleased that she was there’

Answer (score 3):

"I'm touched" is a way to express appreciation for something that's a little less strong and/or formal than "I'm honored". It does have some connotation of sentimentality, though, which might not be what you're going for.

Comment: I didn't have that constraint in mind and the more the merrier anyway- for future readers.

Comment: To me, touched has a danger of actually sounding more special, as "that touched me" can be seen as something very strong, moving, and rare.  Touching sentiments to me conjure almost the image of a tear coming to the eye, and a pause to reflect.  Still, I can definitely also recognize a usage/intention as to lesser significance as well.  But I believe it would be ambiguous or elicit different responses/understandings from different people.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest I think you're right. It probably is open to interpretation when the way you put it made me realize that it's more likely to be interpreted as stronger.

And I know I'm going against the site's rules here by inviting all collections but I don't think 15 points vs 10 points was the motivation behind them. In this particular case, having a nice list of synonyms of honors and their use cases would probably serve the site more if anything.

Comment: I'm not as active here as some, but I don't believe it heavily goes against EL&U rules.  Although it's subjective, it has legitimate answers of proper usage, and isn't just based on opinion... seems quite similar to typical word request questions to me.  Indeed it may be a little less helped by quoting definitions, which isn't taken as friendly, but if anything, the fault is on our answers, not your question.  That there may not be terrific answers isn't to great fault on you!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it will be hard to garner definitions that really gauge the degree of potency different words will have in this phrase, as they're often subtle, having changed over time, becoming cliche or shifting by associated usages, and different from the word standing alone.  Plus they may often even vary just based upon challenging context changes.  Consider even the phrase "thank you", it can be a passive (even dismissive) phrase just to meet cultural expectation... or can be used with passionate or intimate deep-seated gratitude.  Many phrases will change meaning in different locations or contexts.

I suppose my best suggestion for trying to convey your lack of passion would be **I'm appreciative**.  "Appreciation" seems more generally seen as a more middle-ground response, in comparison to responses like "awe" or "overwhelmed".  Acts that go more in hand with appreciation to me are applause rather than ovation... and a thank you card rather than a deep debt of gratitude.  A lot of this may come from the word being more conected to an intellectual response rather than an emotional response, as indicated by many of the related usages of the word...

> -The act of estimating the qualities of things and giving them their proper value.
>   -Clear perception or recognition, especially of aesthetic quality:
>   a course in art appreciation.
>   -An increase or rise in the value of property, goods, etc.
>   -Critical notice; evaluation; opinion, as of a situation, person, etc.
>   [(Dictionary.com)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/appreciation)

Ironically, another option might actually be **I'm thankful**.  Despite the opportunity for the word to convey deeper meaning as noted above, it seems to be taken as rather basic and minimal in such usage.  Usually a more emotional gratitude has additional indications, and in isolation is best heard in a voice rather than in text.  I believe, at least here in America, someone who is really moved will be driven to find a more emotive word than simply thankful.  Alternatively, to even more give a basic appreciation without any sign of depth to your response, I'd just go with **thank you** or **thanks** as being very basic, and having the benefit of avoiding introducing you as a subject into the topic at all, any usage of which may signal an extra response.

To me flattered, delighted, hono(u)red, and touched all show much more passion than thankful or appreciative.  But I believe all such phrases will subtly vary depending upon your location and audience.

Answer (score 0):

*Tickled*. It's part touched, part honored, part grateful and light-hearted.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tickle)
>
> If something tickles you, you find it funny or it makes you happy

Hence it could be argued that you are tickled by the honor in the sense that it makes you happy.

Or use *tickled pink*:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tickled-pink)
>
> informal: very pleased:
>
> *I was tickled pink to be invited.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In the Ken Dodd register.